# $x^3+7=y^2$ find all natural solutions

Tags: number-theory

$x^3+7=y^2$
find all solutions in natural numbers

I tried to check  a residue of the division on
$3,4,5,7,9,12,13$

I want to prove that this equation has not solutions because left part gives some residue and right part other. Actually I don't know is it true . And am I on right way of solving this problem? But I proved this for
$x^3+7=y^4$ by checking residues when dividing on $13$
If I'm on right way ,can you say division of what I need to check , to get the result?
If not tell me please what to do.

Comment: Can you show your work for mod 13?

Comment: Familiar with [elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve)?

Comment: See Keith Conrad's exposition of V. A. Lebesgue's method of solving this Mordell equation here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y^2 = x^3 + k$ is known an Mordell's equation.

You are right that there are no integer solutions. However, I believe that a naive modulo residue check doesn't yield

Here's a suggested approach, which requires you to fill in some gaps

1. Assume that an integral solution exists. Show that $x$ is odd.
2. Write $ y^2 + 1 = x^3 + 8 = (x+2)(x^2 - 2x + 4 )$
3. Hence there is a prime $p$ such that $ p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ and $ y^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, which is a contradiction.

Note: There are 2 ways of doing 3, based on what is written (and some gaps).